# Glide for Android: How to include GIFs from Google Drive?

Tags: java, android, imageview, gif, android-glide

I am trying to include GIFs in my android application. My GIFs are shared as a document on Google Drive with public access enabled. Currently, I'm trying to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to include the GIFs.

```
 Glide.with(parent.getContext())
            .asGif()
            .load("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1-QKgZ76K3EZQlbXyY3wI57FA8k31JmrA")
            .into(imageView);
```

However, although there is no error, the GIF does not display on my phone, even after a long time(internet issues shouldn't be the problem).

It appears that this is only a problem for GIFs on google drive. Trying to show an internet GIF such as [this one](https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/bored_animation.gif) works on my Android phone.

How can I show GIF files on Google Drive with Glide on my Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Because Glide trying to fetch image which type you specified. I just tried it and its work. it loads too late. If you wait a bit, you will see that it can be loaded. You can test it more easily if you upload a lower resolution gif file to Drive.

[image: Test]

Comment: Thanks! How can I make the gifs load faster?

Comment: You can use diskCacheStrategy and thumbnail for loading faster in frontend.